# Wamp server is not starting all the services on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: wampserver

I am trying to install a wamp server on windows 7 64 bit machine..but icon of wamp server is orange.when i tested the services for apache from wamp server i am getting the message as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzocN.jpg)your port 80 is actually used by : server : Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0.How to turn wamp server green?Please suggest..

Comment: Try using a different port, by changing the same in the ini file

Comment: i tried by doing the below changes in http.conf file.If you don’t have another editor to use, just use CTRL-F in Notepad and search for the ##Listen command within the file. Then change the commands to match the following (assuming port 7080), replacing “:80” with “:7080” in both places. (Listen 12.34.5.6.78:80 is preceded by a # – it’s a commented line.) And it works successfully for me. Thanks vinay for your help.